# Show message when RowFilter doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a RowFilter with JavaScript for my table, everything works fine but when text from search input doesn't match I would like to show a message (No results found... inside the table in a < td >) but I don't know exactly how to do that, here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="buscar" placeholder="search..." />
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="Tabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Level</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>This is my name</td>
          <td>Level Master 45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>This is my name number 2</td>
          <td>Level Master 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>This is my name number 3</td>
          <td>Level Mastermind 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr />

  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    RowFilter();
});

function RowFilter() {
  var busqueda = document.getElementById('buscar');
  var table = document.getElementById("Tabla").tBodies[0];

  buscaTabla = function() {
    texto = busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
    var r = 0;
    while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
      if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1)
        row.style.display = null;
      else {
        row.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

  busqueda.addEventListener('keyup', buscaTabla);

}
```

And here is a demo in JSFiddle

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9p9ycbcb/1/)

I tried to show an alert in the else part of the while in the js function but the alert is shown a lot of times (while row = table.rows[r++]). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fork of your original JSFiddle that displays a message when there are no search results.

https://jsfiddle.net/reid_horton/yg98jqcj/

First, add the element you wish to display to the HTML above (or in) your table.

```
<div id="no-results">
  No results!
</div>
```

Set it to hide by default.

```
#no-results {
  display: none;
}
```

To detect when there are no search results, change your loop to this.

```
var didMatch = false;
var r = 0;
while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
  if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
    row.style.display = null;
    didMatch = true;
  } else {
    row.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
if (!didMatch) {
    noResults.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    noResults.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The `didMatch` variable is used to keep track of if any results matched. When it is true, you hide `#no-results`, and when it is false, you show it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#buscar").on("input",function(){

        $value = $(this).val();

        $("tr").not(":first").hide();

        $len = $("td:contains(" + $value + ")").closest("tr").show().length;

        if($len < 1)
            $(".no").show(1000);

        else
            $(".no").hide();


    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .no {
                border: 1px solid gray;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: skyblue;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #fff;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="buscar" placeholder="search..." />
  <hr />
           <div class="no">No Result</div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="Tabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Level</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>This is my name</td>
          <td>Level Master 45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>This is my name number 2</td>
          <td>Level Master 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>This is my name number 3</td>
          <td>Level Mastermind 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr />

  </div>

</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#buscar").on("input",function(){
        
        $value = $(this).val();
        
        $("tr").not(":first").hide();
        
        $len = $("td:contains(" + $value + ")").closest("tr").show().length;
        
        if($len < 1)
            $(".no").show(1000);
        
        else
            $(".no").hide();
        
                      
    })
})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @F.Flores , Check my Answer!